# How to open transaction from business object using JDBC Java

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions

I have a project that is structured like this

Business Logic Layer -->> DAO layer -->> QueryExecuter

Business Object calls dao layer and dao layer then called QueryExecuter class to execute the query. The QueryExecuter class is as follows

```java
public class QueryExecutor {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(QueryExecutor.class);

//java.sql.Connection
private Connection connection;

public QueryExecutor(){

    //apache commons db utils QueryRunner object.
    queryRunner = new QueryRunner( );
    initilizeConnection();
}


private QueryRunner queryRunner;
private QueryResult queryResult = new QueryResult();


private void initilizeConnection(){

    LOG.info("Getting Connection ");
    try {
        this.connection = FitClineConnectionManager.getInstance().getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        LOG.fatal("Problem Getting connection ");
        LOG.fatal(e.getMessage());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.fatal("Problem Getting connection ");
        LOG.fatal(e.getMessage());

    } catch (PropertyVetoException e) {
        LOG.fatal("Problem Getting connection ");
        LOG.fatal(e.getMessage());

    }
}

public QueryResult saveAndReturnId(String sql , Object[] params )  {

    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    try {

        connection = getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS); 

        queryRunner.fillStatement( statement, params);

        statement.executeUpdate();
        rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();

        queryResult.setLastInsertedId( new AutoGeneratedKeyHandler().handle( rs ) );
        queryResult.setStatus( QUERY_STATUS.SUCCESS.getCode() );

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if ( e.getSQLState().equalsIgnoreCase("23000")  ){
            queryResult.setError( ErrorCodeProperties.getInstance().get_00004() );
        }

        LOG.error(e.getMessage());

    } finally{

        if ( statement != null ){
            try {
                //closing statement
                DbUtils.close( statement );

            } catch (SQLException e) {
                LOG.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        closeConnection();
    }
    return queryResult;
}
}
```

In this structure , connections are managed in QueryExecuter class, how do I open transaction from Business Layer b/c connections are managed in QueryExecuter class. And I want connection object in my Business Layer to do so. Is there any smart way to achieve this.
I am not using any dependency injection in my project, Just apache commons DBUtils and jdbc.

P.S. In current scenario, QueryExecuter object is composed inside base Dao class, so multiple method call(for transaction) will result in multiple connection acquiring from pool.

Comment: seems you need a transaction manager to do that! check with spring transaction manager! Also, it is recommended to use DI in most of situation! I love it!

Comment: @Rugal Yes that is the final choice, I am searching for the smart way of doing it without Dependency Injection or otherwise I will use Spring  Transaction Manager.